# Testing un-compilable code in NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a class which for now should always have a certain member populated before it is valid. To enforce this, the class has no default constructor and instead has a constructor which accepts a value for that required member. The setup is similar to this below:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string Owner { get; protected set; }

  public MyClass(string owner)
  {
    this.Owner = owner;
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to write a test to ensure that there is in fact no default constructor, so that if one gets added in the future, we are reminded of the reasons behind not having one and are forced to consider the impact of doing so. Although, obviously attempting to call the default constructor in a test won't just fail, it won't compile.

Is there a good way to pull off this kind of test without modifying my original class? If not, I suppose I could implement a default constructor which throws an exception. My only hesitation there is that calling the default constructor now becomes compilable code and then we must rely on other tests to ensure such code doesn't get written.

Thoughts?

Comment: Whatever solution you come up with I'd recommend documenting the importance of the missing default constructor in the class itself so you are not relying on a test that, may or may not, be run in the future. Sure the next developer might just ignore those comments its another level :-)

Comment: Tests should be run on the build server, so that if it fails, the build breaks.  Relying on developers to run tests is always a bad idea - without continuous integration, unit tests would never work.

Comment: @womp: Agreed but run on the build server or not individual tests can still be enabled/disabled and that was my point. Relying that a test in some other part of the project will continue to be run forever is not unreasonable but not guaranteed either. At least with the comments in the class you are making all possible efforts to make people aware. Maybe more so than the test alone since a future developer won't know the "why" relating to a particular tests existence. Cover all bases was my point I guess.

Comment: Tests should really be documented.  When they break, people need to know what the point of the test was in the first place.  So I agree, but I prefer a combination of both the test and the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could call [`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) to try to run the default constructor, and assert that a `MissingMethodException` is thrown.

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(MissingMethodException))
public void ShouldBeNoDefaultConstructorForMyClass()
{
    Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));
}
```

Comment: -1, why invoke it when you can simply assert that it's not there?

Comment: +1 - exactly what I needed. To answer John, you can do it either way. Since people can choose one or the other, and both answer the question asked, why would you DV a valid answer just because it's not the path you'd elect to take?

Answer (score 9):

I would create a default constructor, mark it private and put your documentation there.  Then your reasons for doing it won't be hidden off somewhere.  You have to realize you'll be giving up some serialization functionality that requires the parameterless constructor.

Comment: I prefer this way over the Unit Test concept in this case because Unit Tests often times fall by the wayside, whereas code with comments is there right in your face when you try to change it. After all, you're not trying to test functionality in this case, but rather programming style or a programming norm, which is not really what a Unit Test is for.

Comment: I prefer a combination of both.  I always postulate that tests should have the business reason documented.  The good thing about the test though, is that it forces compliance by breaking the build.  Documentation does not.

Answer (score 5):

```
ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
Assert.IsNull(ci);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this page on dynamically invoking constructors.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0400__Reflection/Dynamicallyinvokingconstructors.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you could use reflection to check if there is a no arg constructor for the class and fail the test if there is

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  A good way would be to use reflection to try a parameterless constructor within a try/catch.